# Confused about combinatorials

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How do I solve 4$\cdot$6 = 8$\cdot$3 by a combinatorial proof? How can I start this proof? I know that I can show a two pictures that represent 24 but I'm not entirely sure how to go about this. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

**Completely revised:** Since this is in the context of elementary combinatorics, I suspect that you’re intended to apply the multiplication principle. Consider the following problem:

> How many three-digit numbers $abc$ are there in which $a\in\{1,2\}$, $b\in\{1,2,3\}$, and $c\in\{1,2,3,4\}$?

Now calculate this in two ways:

1. First count the ways to choose $a$ and $b$. Then count the ways to combine one of these $ab$ combinations with a choice of $c$.
2. First count the ways to choose $a$ and $c$. Then count the ways to combine that choice with a choice of $b$.

Comment: The dimensions of each rectangle would be 4x6 and 8x4. Is that correct? I get stuck after this point explaining my proof.

Comment: I mean 6x4 and 8x3

Comment: @Nick: Yes, that’s right. The rest of the argument is that the area of a rectangle is the product of its side dimensions, and by actual count of unit squares these rectangles have the same area, so ...

Comment: So if I show two rectangles by these dimensions and conclude by the multiplication principle of the side dimensions that these two rectangles have the same area than I proved it by combinatorial proof?

Comment: @Nick: It really depends on just how one interprets *combinatorial proof*. This argument is borderline. Give me some context: what sort of material are you studying? I may be able to make it a bit more obviously combinatorial.

Comment: Combinatorial proof is showing two ways on how to count same thing. I just learned the basics with the definition of additive and multiplication principles.

Comment: @Nick: Okay, so you’re studying very elementary combinatorics. In that context I’ll modify the answer a little; it shouldn’t take more than a few minutes.

Comment: Ahh I see that...quick question, how did you come up with those sets because I have another problem just like this one where its $2\cdot6$=$3\cdot4$?

Comment: @Nick: I wanted a factorization of $24$ into three factors that could be combined in two ways to produce $6\cdot 4$ and $8\cdot 3$. You can do it with $12$ just as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8771/discussion-between-nick-martucci-and-brian-m-scott)

Comment: I see that I got 24 combinations from the example you gave me. I need 12 combinations and 2,3,4 are factors of 12 so how do I get 12 combinations instead of 24 from those factors?

Comment: @Nick: Two of your factors will be $2$ and $3$, so the remaining one must be ... ?

Comment: Is the answer 2?

Comment: @Nick: Yep. You can split $2\cdot2\cdot3$ in two useful ways for your other problem, making it exactly like this problem, but with different numbers.

Comment: Ahhh I see it now...thank you so much!!! I can show all the factors I get which for problem 1 would be 24 and for problem 2 would be 12 and by showing those factors and using the multiplication principle definition does that mean I explained it by a combinatorial proof?

Comment: @Nick: It’s my best guess at what’s intended when you’re asked for a combinatorial proof here. The term basically means showing that two expressions are equal by showing that they count the same set in two different ways, and that’s what we’re doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a combinatorial/pictorial proof. The image was made using the awesome [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) package in LaTeX.

[image]